# How to count total ticks of event loop (NodeJs)?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I'm learning nodejs event loop. I'm curious if we can count total ticks event loop took throughout the application runtime?

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Hey there!")
}, 1000);
```

As per my understanding, event loop will tick total 2 times before the application ends. How can I make node tell me exact number of ticks?

Answer (score 0):

The event loop is a system for scheduling tasks and async operations, it uses Queues and Stack under the hood to process function calls.
Whenever you get a result of a function, this means the function was put in the Queue and the pushed in to the stack.
This way we have non-blocking operation. What you are trying to do does not make any sense to me, every time you get a log from a function it means this function was processed both by the queue and the stack.

Comment: I'm undertaking "Nodejs: Advanced Concepts" course by Stephen Grider. He explained event loop using a pseudo code and explained the concept of 'ticks' in event loop. I asked the question in that reference.